# How can I calculate requested CPU and RAM in the CloudSim plus?

Tags: cloudsim

I want to implement a new VmAllocation policy in the CloudSim plus. How can I calculate the requested CPU and RAM? Also, I want to loop over all the hosts to figure out the current resource utilization in each host. How can I do this?